# How to account for stretching in graph transformation of $y = \sqrt{x}$?

Tags: functions, transformation

[image: square_root_graph]

[image: transformation_of_square_root_graph]

Hi guys, I got this question as an assignment from my university and have been trying to solve it for a whole day now but can't get the correct answer. Well, I know how to shift Graph towards left, right, upwards and downwards $C$ points. Well for example current Graph's equation is $y = x^2$ and if we have to move graph to left $C$ points. We will add $C$ to the function and it will become $y = (x+C)^2$ and if we have to shift Graph to right side $C$ points, then we will subtract $C$ from function, and the equation will become $y = (x-C)^2$, and similarly add $C$ to the $f(x)$ and subtract $C$ from $f(x)$ if we want to shift graph upwards $C$ points and downwards $C$ points respectively, and if we want to reflect it about $x$-axis, we will multiply $f(x)$ with minus "-" sign and if we want to reflect it about $y$-axis we will multiply the function with minus"-" sign thats makes it like $y = f(-x)$. Well now you now that I know these things. But I have been trying to solve this question and its been a day but I am not able to solve it correctly. Kindly help me, I want to submit my Assignment and I really do not want to lose even a single marks from Mathematics.

And yeah I forgot to tell that I have already figured out that the graph in second picture is reflected about $x$-axis and then moved $1$ unit/point toward left side and moved $1$ unit/point downwards, but if you look carefully the graph in second picture is little stretched as well and thats where I am getting problem because I am not figuring out that is it stretched towards x-direction or y-direction and also can't figure out that how many points/units it have stretched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original graph has been stretched by factor $3$ in the $y$ direction, reflected in the $x$ axis, and translated by $-1$ in both $x$ and $y$ directions.

Therefore your new graph is $$y=-1-3\sqrt{x+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

Good work so far.

> I am not figuring out that is it stretched towards x-direction or
>   y-direction

Here's how to get started on that.

The transformations that stretch are the ones that replace $x$ by $ax$ or $y$ by $by$. To figure out which stretch you need and the value of the constant, look at a few easy interesting points on the graphs (after you've reflected and translated so that the new one starts at the origin and heads off into the first quadrant).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**  We know that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ grows from $0$ to $1$ as $x$ increases from $0$ to $1$ and that $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ grows from $0$ to $2$ as $x$ increases from $0$ to $4$.  If we call the second function $g$, then $g$ decreases by $3$ as $x$ increases from $-1$ to $0$ (one unit to the right of the endpoint) and decreases by $6$ as $x$ increases from $-1$ to $3$ (four units to the right of the endpoint).  What factor do you need to multiply the square root by in order to account for this transformation?